# Event listener when connecting to a wifi network

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap

I am building an app with cordova for android. I would like to know if there is any way to add an event listener to notify me when the user connects to a wifi network. For example when he/she is  using the phone data and connects to a wifi network, I would like to get notified and the same for when the user changes from wifi to data again.

The only way I can think of doing this is to create a `setInterval` every X miliseconds and check the network information with the `plugin cordova-plugin-network-information`. But doing that seems very inefficient, and I would like to get notified immediatly.

So is there any way/plugin to add an event listener when there is a network change?

**EDIT**: I'm not using ionic, just backbone and jquery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Ionic then you can do this:

```
// watch network for a connection
let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('network connected!');
  // We just got a connection but we need to wait briefly
   // before we determine the connection type. Might need to wait.
  // prior to doing any api requests as well.
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.network.type === 'wifi') {
      console.log('we got a wifi connection, woohoo!');
    }
  }, 3000);
});

// stop connect watch
connectSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

(Code from [Ionic Native Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/))

With Cordova there is a plugin called **cordova-plugin-network-information**, that you can download from [Github](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information)

With that you can write stuff like that:

```
document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);

function onOnline() {
   if(checkConnection===Connection.WIFI){
      // Code
   }
}

function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    console.log("Connection: "+states[networkState])

    return networkState
}
```

I have not tested the Cordova example tho

Comment: Sorry I'm just using backbone, no ionic.  Would this work if the user is already connected, but just switching from data to wifi?

Comment: @Pablo second example is Cordova only. I dont really know - you would have to try. But if not you could create a workaround with setTimeout()

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but it seems the only way to do it is with an interval.

Comment: Little update. The event listener does fire when changing networks. So your answer works perfectly!

Comment: @Pablo Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you only get notified when app goes [online/offline](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/index.html#online) and a quick reminder through the Internet confirm my doubts. I guess the way to know the connection type is to check each second if the network has changed using a `setTimeout` or a `setInterval`.

Comment: If I end up using a setInterval or setTimeout, is there any drawbacks of doing this app-performance wise? Is it a bad practise to do so?

Comment: Not really if you do this each second. Could affect to performance if you do each 50ms for example